# How do i make functions code as shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I’d like to move Woocommerce`s Additional information field into the Accordion tap, which is below “add to cart” button.

I put the Accordion tap to shortcode using plugin already.

And created Shortcode using the code below, but it doesn’t work normally.

```
in functions.php file 

include('custom-shortcode.php');
//remove additional_information and reviews tabs
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );
function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);

    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );  // Removes the reviews tab
    return $tabs;
}

in custom-shortcode.php
 
 function additional_info_under_add_to_cart( ) {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
   }
}
 add_shortcode('custom-shortcode', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart');
```

I can insert Additional information field using [custom-shortcode] into accordion, but it’s not put in the accordion tap but on another location.

Please let me know how do i solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: what does not work properly?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. i atteched screenshot here -> [link](https://i.imgur.com/SIqXEXy.jpg). I think the code is somthing wrong.

Comment: How do you add your shortcode in php?